# How to Rotate an image inside a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios

I have a UIScrollView which has an UIImageView in it.
I need to be able to to rotate the image.
rotation gestures are being intercepted by the ScrollView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` directly on the Scrollview. But use it for your subview.
(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [`transform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) property of UIView:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(/*angle*/);
```