# Rotating UIImageView in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`. The ultimate goal is to rotate, pan and zoom the image within the confines of the `UIScrollView`. The panning and zooming are working great. The rotating works initially, however after a rotation is complete, followed by a pinch zoom, the image rotation gets reset to 0 and the image is displaced outside of the `UIScrollView`.

Any suggestion's to what I may be missing

```
@IBOutlet weak var innerScrollView: UIScrollView!
        private weak var innerImageView: UIImageView?
        var beforeImage: UIImage?


        // MARK: -
        // MARK: UIViewController       

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            innerScrollView.delegate = self
            configureScrollView(innerScrollView, image: beforeImage)

            let recognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "rotateRecognizer:")
            if let imageView = innerImageView {
                imageView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            }
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            resetScrollView(innerScrollView)
        }



        // MARK: -
        // MARK: Private Helpers

        private func resetScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

            let scaleWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
            let scaleHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height

            let minScale = min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth)

            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
            scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
            centerScrollViewContents()

        }

        private func configureScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView, image: UIImage?) {

            guard let img = image else {
                return
            }
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: img.size)
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            scrollView.contentSize = img.size

            innerImageView = imageView
        }

        private func centerScrollViewContents() {
            let boundsSize = innerScrollView.bounds.size
            var contentsFrame = innerImageView!.frame

            if contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width {
                contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0
            } else {
                contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0
            }

            if contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height {
                contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0
            } else {
                contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0
            }

            innerImageView!.frame = contentsFrame
        }

        func rotateRecognizer(recognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {

            print("The content Offset is \(innerScrollView.contentOffset)")
            guard let recView = recognizer.view else {
                return
            }

            recView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recView.transform, recognizer.rotation);
            recognizer.rotation = 0;
        }



        // MARK: -
        // MARK: UIGestureRecognizer Delegate Protocol

        func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

            if let imageView = scrollView.subviews.first as? UIImageView {
                return imageView
            }
            return nil
        }
```

Comment: So post your pan gesture recognizer code. That's likely where the problem is. I bet you're starting from the identity transform rather than from the image view's current transform. (Your rotate method is doing the right thing and starting from the current transform.)

Comment: @DuncanC Well, I don't have pan or pinch gesture recognizer. I'm using the UIScrollView. Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you be rotating innerImageView, not "recView"?

Comment: If you are manipulating the scroll view's transform then yes that is likely the problem. you should probably apply your rotation to the image view, not to the scroll view. (although getting the center of rotation to work right might be a challenge.)

Answer (score 0):

I made it work. There is another proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721241/how-to-rotate-an-image-inside-a-uiscrollview), but mine is different.

Scaling and panning works easily with scrollview, but when adding rotation, it is reset immediately you make another pan like you said (it happened for me too). What I did was to ditch the scrollView's gestures entirely and not rely on its delegates. I added my own gesture recognizers for pan, zoom and rotation. Then, you can combine them as you like: to allow two of them to simultaneously sense changes, or even all 3 of them. In my solution, I wanted the pan to be sensed separately and zoom and rotation to be sensed together. You do this in the method:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

See the rest of my code below. Of course, in my example I have a UIView, not image view, but that doesn't matter from the transforms point of view.

```
private struct Constants {
    private init() {}

    static let minZoom = CGFloat(0.3)
    static let maxZoom = CGFloat(6)
}

private var activeView: UIView
private var savedTransform: CGAffineTransform

// Represents rotation performed since the last transform save
private var editedRotation = TransformConstants.defaultRotation
// Represents scaling performed since the last transform save
private var editedScale = TransformConstants.defaultScale

override func didPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: activeView)
    activeView.transform = savedTransform.translatedBy(x: translation.x, y: translation.y)

    if shouldSaveGestures(recognizer: recognizer) {
      saveChanges(operation: .pan)
      return
    }
}

override func didPinch(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if shouldSaveGestures(recognizer: recognizer) {
      saveChanges(operation: .zoom)
      return
    }

    var scale = recognizer.scale

    if Constants.minZoom > scale * savedTransform.getScale().x {
      scale = Constants.minZoom / savedTransform.getScale().x
    } else if scale * savedTransform.getScale().x > Constants.maxZoom {
      scale = Constants.maxZoom / savedTransform.getScale().x
    }

    activeView.transform = savedTransform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale).rotated(by: editedRotation)
    editedScale = CGPoint(x: scale, y: scale)
}

override func didRotate(recognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    if shouldSaveGestures(recognizer: recognizer) {
      saveChanges(operation: .rotate)
      return
    }

    activeView.transform = savedTransform.scaledBy(x: editedScale.x, y: editedScale.y).rotated(by: recognizer.rotation)
    editedRotation = recognizer.rotation
}

private func shouldSaveGestures(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return recognizer.state == .ended || recognizer.state == .failed
}

private func saveChanges(operation: OperationType) {
    savedTransform = activeView.transform
    editedScale = TransformConstants.defaultScale
    editedRotation = TransformConstants.defaultRotation
}
```